# Why is a painted dot disappears sometime?

Tags: vb.net, paint

I try to paint a dot on an image
…

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\SHEMMY-7X64\Pictures\postage.jpg")
            Using p As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Yellow, 4)
                Using g As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
                    g.DrawEllipse(p, 15, 5, 10, 10)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Sub
```

The image is painted but not the dot.
When separating the code to 2 steps:
1. Load the image

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\SHEMMY-7X64\Pictures\postage.jpg")
    End Sub
```

2. paint

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Using p As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Yellow, 4)
            Using g As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
                g.DrawEllipse(p, 15, 5, 10, 10)
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
```

This time the dot was painted.
I posted this question at an another site and was told it's a question of timing.

Ok it's a question of timing, but how to solve it?

Comment: NEVER call `CreateGraphics`.  ALWAYS draw on a control in its `Paint` event handler using the `Graphics` object provided.  Every time the `Paint` event is raised, anything drawn on the control is erased.  If you expect the drawing to be permanent, you have redo it on every `Paint` event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw everything including the image. You could:

Create a class level variable of `Bitmap` type and name it say, Bmp:

```vb
Private Bmp as Bitmap
```

To load a new image:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'dispose the old image if any:
    bmp?.Dispose()

    'and assing the new one:
    bmp = New Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\SHEMMY-7X64\Pictures\postage.jpg"))

    'and call:
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Now the painting routine:

```vb
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If bmp IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
        Dim desRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
        Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics

        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

        G.Clear(BackColor) 'or: G.Clear(Parent.Backcolor) if you want.
        G.DrawImage(bmp, desRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        Using pn As New Pen(Color.Yellow, 4)
            G.DrawEllipse(pn, 15, 5, 10, 10)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, don't forget to clean up:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    bmp?.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Good luck.

Comment: I tried using pant event and it works perfectly.
Thank you JQSOFT

Comment: @shemmy if this answered your question, you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Yes, it defiantly answer my question

Comment: @shemmy [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is described how you can accept an answer (and reward JQSOFT for his time spent helping you)